# Need help mapping in json fetch

Tags: reactjs, json, fetch

Can anyone see where I mess up this fetch?
Error message; TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

[This is how the data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oF5J.png)

Happy for any help!

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const PressReleaseList = () => {
  const [pressReleases, setPressReleases] = useState([null]);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async function () {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(
          'https://feed.mfn.se/v1/feed/3XXXXX.json'
        );
        const json = await res.json();
        setPressReleases(json.items);
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Main>
      {pressReleases.items.map((item) => (
        <TextCell key={item.news_id}>
          <CategoryText>{item.title}</CategoryText>
        </TextCell>
      ))}
      ;
    </Main>
  );
```

Comment: You are trying to access twice to `items`. Try setting `setPressReleases` only with the json variable or apply the `map` function to `pressReleases` directly.

Comment: That worked! Thanks! 
Still, nothing gets printed out in the browser though. Says ; Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {entity_id, slug, slugs, name, brand_image_url, isins, leis, local_refs, tickers}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Any suggestions? 
    {pressReleases.map((item) => (
        <TextCell key={item.news_id}>
          <CategoryText>{item.subjects}</CategoryText>
        </TextCell>
      ))}
      ;

Comment: That error could be happening because you are trying to render `item.subjects` in the JSX Element. I think `subjects` must be a list, therefore it's an object  and you can only render primitives, such as a string or a number. I'm posting this comment and the previous one as an answer, if I'm right please mark it as the solution.

Comment: Yes! That was the problem! Thank you!!

Comment: You mark another one. This is my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69500389/16602311).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access twice to items. Try setting setPressReleases only with the json variable or apply the map function to pressReleases directly.

And given the error code in your comment, we can see that you are trying to render a list (`item.subjects`) in a JSX Element instead of primitives.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your `key={item.news_id}`. Looks like `item` is missing an 's,' should be `key={items.news_id}` based off your screenshot.

Comment: i don't think that should matter, its it that you could call it anything once your in the .map? so I could name it{ pressReleases.items.map((yeah) => (
        <TextCell key={yeah.news_id}> ... but not sure. It did not help to add an s anyway

Answer (score 0):

Initially when your loop runs (before the Ajax call completes), it's running the `.map` on an array whose only child is a `null` (derived from `const [pressReleases, setPressReleases] = useState([null]);`).

Within your loop, when you're calling `item.news_id` you're essentially doing `null.news_id` thus your app crashes.

Change your useState to the following:

```
const [pressReleases, setPressReleases] = useState([]);
```

This will ensure you have an empty array, thus you don't ever loop until you have data.